# Check The Client's Authenticated Status (web-services)

Tags: java, web-services

everybody.

Say, I have a web server and a client, which connects to it for the first time. The authentication mechanism is:

```
1) parse the client's  UsernameToken element and retrieve its username, password and   
   nonce.
2) evaluate a hash: SHA2 (username + password + nonce)
3) check if a Data Base contains such a hash.
```

Let's assume that there is such a hash. The question is, how to know that the client is already authenticated, when it connects the second time?

- Searching the DB is rather expensive, so I can't do it at every connect.
- Saving the clients hash in memory will increase the performance, but how long should it present in such a registry and it seem to be a huge security hole.
- Session parameter? But how can it be implemented in the web-services context?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592330/restful-web-service-authentication and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication to get some ideas.

Comment: Well, there are interesting points. So, am I right that I can create a session somehow (it would be grate if somebody could share an article on it =) ) and use hash(username/password/nonce) to identify it. If the session exists - the user is authenticated?